# Where should I be retrieving the user principal in an ASP.NET Web Forms app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iprincipal

Assuming a fairly general use case in an ASP.NET Web Forms application, where should I be retrieving my principal + identity?

I'm aware that there are generally two ways to go about it:

- `HttpContext.Current.User`
- `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`

I'm speculating that using `HttpContext` will run the risk of a current context not existing (i.e. `HttpContext.Current == null`) on some edge cases, but I more often see code that use this instead of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` (which I assume is safer, as it *should* always exist?).

Why is this? What implications am I getting myself into if I pick one or the other?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx

Comment: Awesome. If you'd like to wing that in as a formal answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Rep whoring initiated :) Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rep whoring here I come :)

Mr. Hanselman has already blogged about this here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx

The basic idea is that 99% of the time.. they are the same.. although it's possible to change them.